# Orthonormal vectors in Polar coordinates, show $\hat{e}_R=\frac{(x,y,z)}{r}$

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

> **Definitions**
>
> *Unit vector has length 1. Orthonormal vectors are orthogonal and unit vectors.*

RobJohn's suggestions for the basis in polar coordinates, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3949946#3949946), satisfy the criteria but how can you approach this geometrically? And how to make sure they are actually orthogonal in polar coordinates?

$$\begin{align}   \hat{e}_R&=\frac{(x,y,z)}{r}\\   \hat{e}_\theta&=\frac{(-y,x,0)}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}\\   \hat{e}_\phi&=\frac{(-xz,-yz,r^2-z^2)}{r\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}   \end{align}$$

**Perhaps related**

1. [Visual Ways to Remember Cross products of Unit vectors? Cross-product in $\mathbb F^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124089/visual-ways-to-remember-cross-product-in-mathbb-f3) (third vector from two other unit vectors)
2. [Explain Dot product with Partial derivatives in Polar-coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124056/explain-dot-product-with-partial-derivatives-in-polar-coordinates) (orthogonality check)
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124447/mnemonics-for-the-clockwiseness-with-polar-coordinates

> <sub>**Example problem** (about page 817 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/materiaali/Mat-1_1020_juhani_pitkaranta__tkk_n_laaja_matematiikka_ii__2007_.pdf?state:CourseAdditionalMaterial=BrO0ABXcgAAAAAgAAGWVkaXRVc2VyV2FudHNUb0NoYW5nZUZpbGVzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHAAdxMAABBlZGl0RGlhbG9nSGlkZGVuc3EAfgAAAQ%3D%3D))</sub>
>
> $$\nabla\cdot\bar{F}=\left(\hat{e}_{R}\partial_{R}+\frac{1}{R}\hat{e}_{\theta}\partial_{\theta}+
>  \frac{1}{R\sin(\theta)}
>  \hat{e}_{\phi}\partial_{\phi}\right)\cdot\bar{F}$$
>
> where
>
> $$\bar{F}=R^3 (
>  \cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)\bar{i}+\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\bar{j}+\cos(\theta)\bar{k})‌​.$$

Comment: Usually, a unit vector is not required to be orthogonal to anything else.  It sounds as if you are trying to define an orthonormal set, but you are only using a single vector. Normally, a unit vector is a vector whose length is $1$.

Comment: @robjohn: yes thank you. Well after learning the case 1, it is easy to learn the other cases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\hat{e}_R$ is the unit radial vector.  This is simply $(x,y,z)$ divided by its length, $r$: $\hat{e}_R=\frac{(x,y,z)}{r}$.

$\hat{e}_\theta$ is the unit vector tangent to the sphere, thus perpendicular to $(x,y,z)$, which is also perpendicular to $(0,0,1)$ since changing $\theta$ does not change $z$. Therefore, we simply need to take the cross product of $(x,y,z)$ and $(0,0,1)$ and normalize to get $\hat{e}_\theta=\frac{(-y,x,0)}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$. The sign is chosen so that the vector points counter-clockwise.

$\hat{e}_\phi$ is perpendicular to the other two, so we take the cross product and normalize: $\hat{e}_\phi=\frac{(-xz,-yz,r^2-z^2)}{r\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$. Again, the sign is chosen to have positive $z$ component.

Thus, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{e}_R&=\frac{(x,y,z)}{r}\\
\hat{e}_\theta&=\frac{(-y,x,0)}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}\\
\hat{e}_\phi&=\frac{(-xz,-yz,r^2-z^2)}{r\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}
\end{align}
$$

<sub>**References**</sub>

1. Source of the polar-coordinate image [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Coord_system_SE_0.svg) from Wikipedia.

Comment: ...could elaborate on this $\hat{e}_\theta=\frac{(-y,x,0)}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$? Which sign? When you do the cross-product, how you think it? I do the matrix thing but I find it slow... Do you think it as a Sarrus-rule [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122534/5902)?

Comment: @hhh: $(x,y,z)\times(0,0,1)=(y,-x,0)$ and $(0,0,1)\times(x,y,z)=(-y,x,0)$ normalizing these gives opposite vectors, so we choose the one that goes counter-clockwise. Both are perpendicular to the vectors specified.

Comment: The image from Wikipedia has $\theta$ and $\varphi$ switched from the way I usually see them, and from the way I have them in my answer.  I will either edit my answer, or generate a new image (probably the latter so that we are copyright safe).

Comment: ...if you generate the picture, please, do not hesitate to include the source code. I moved the clockwiseness -thing [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124447/mnemonics-for-the-clockwiseness-with-polar-coordinates).