# Partial derivatives and orthogonality with polar-coordinates

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates

We are stuck with this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124068/5902) because I cannot understand the following results. I find it hard to visualize this, let alone deduce from that. How to do it?

**Objective to Attack The closely Related Problems with Orthogonal Basis and Dot Products In Polar-coordinates**

> 1. $\left(\hat{e}_{r}\partial_{r}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{r}\hat{e}_{\theta}\partial_{\theta}\right)= 0$
> 2. $\left(\frac{1}{r}\hat{e}_{\theta}\partial_{\theta}\right) 
>         \cdot \left(\hat{e}_{r}\partial_{r}\right) 
>             = \frac{1}{r} \partial_r$
> 3. $\partial_\theta \hat e_r = \hat e_\theta$
> 4. $\partial_\theta \hat e_\theta = -\hat e_r$

**Trials**

> 1. I have some errors there, related to 3-4 apparently.
>
> $$ \left(\hat{e}*{r}\partial*{r}\right) \cdot
>    \left(\frac{1}{r}\hat{e}*{\theta}\partial*{\theta}\right) 
>    =

\left(\hat{e}*{r}\partial*{r}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{r}+
\left(\hat{e}*{r}\partial*{r}\right) \cdot
\left( \hat{e}*{\theta}\partial*{\theta} \right)

## \not

\frac{-\hat{e}_r}{r^2}+

\left(\hat{e}*{r}\cdot\hat{e}*\theta \right) \partial_{r}
\partial_{\theta}

$$

**Perhaps Related**

1. [Explain Dot product with Partial derivatives in Polar-coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124056/explain-dot-product-with-partial-derivatives-in-polar-coordinates)
2. [Orthonormal vectors in Polar coordinates, show $\hat{e}_R=\frac{(x,y,z)}{r}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124008/show-geometrically-hate-r-fracx-y-zr)
3. [Visual Ways to Remember Cross products of Unit vectors? Cross-product in $\mathbb F^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124089/visual-ways-to-remember-cross-product-in-mathbb-f3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some hints:* (not a complete solution)

- I guess once you think about it you find it clear that $$\hat{e}_{r}\cdot\hat{e}_\theta=0$$
  or in words the unit vector along the radial direction is orthogonal to the unit vector along the angular direction.
- I guess the confusion you have originates from the following fact: the unit vectors $\hat{e}_r$ and $\hat{e}_\theta$ themselves depend on the coordinate $(r,\theta)$. This dependence is usually not made explicit but you should always keep that in mind. If you think about it then I guess it is clear. For $\theta=0$ the radial unit vector points along the $x$-axis whereas for $\theta=\pi/2$ the unit vector points along the $y$-axis.
- The last two points hold for an arbitrary rectangular coordinate system. What is special for the polar coordinate system is that even though $\hat{e}_{r,\theta}$ depend on $\theta$ they **do not** depend on $r$, i.e., $$\hat{e}_{r,\theta} = \hat{e}_{r,\theta} (\theta).$$
- The important relations $\partial_\theta \hat e_r(\theta) = \hat e_\theta (\theta)$ and $\partial_\theta \hat e_\theta(\theta) = -\hat e_r(\theta)$, you can check by taking the explicit expressions
  $$\begin{array}\ \hat{e}_r(\theta)&= \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta  \\ \sin \theta \end{pmatrix} &
  \hat{e}_\theta(\theta)&= \begin{pmatrix} -\sin \theta  \\ \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}
  \end{array}$$

With these remarks, it is easy to show that (here, I make the dependence of the unit vectors on the coordinates explicit)
$$\left(\hat{e}_{r}(\theta)\partial_{r}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{r}\hat{e}_{\theta}(\theta) \partial_{\theta}\right)
= \underbrace{\hat{e}_{r}(\theta) \cdot \hat{e}_{\theta}(\theta)}_{=0} 
 \,\left(\partial_{r} \frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} \right) =0  .$$
The other results follow similarly (but I will leave the proof up to you).

Comment: Why is there no $r$ in the $e_r(\theta)$?

Comment: @hhh: There is a typo. The equation you wrote is correct. Also notice that
$$\hat e_r = \frac{{\bf r}}{r} = \hat e_x \frac{x}{r} + \hat e_y \frac{y}{r},$$
but $x/r = \cos\theta$ and $y/r = \sin\theta$, so there is no $r$.